# Subdomain connection time out

Tags: subdomain, configuration

I created a subdomain, but the connection just times out. I checked the zone file and I have one (A)ddress record with a wild card (*) pointing to my server's IP address. As far as I understand, that's the correct setting in the zone file to make sure all subdomains point to my server. Is there something else I am missing? What are ways to troubleshoot this issue?

I have used trace route, ping, and dig to find out more information.

```
ping -> timeout (loss)
trace route -> no conclusion
dig -> tells me that the domain does have an address
```

Comment: Can you ping the IP address as expected? As well, if you cannot ping you cannot trace route since trace route uses ping. Does nslookup resolve the sub-domain name? It is okay to use an IP address for a sub-domain, but if your parent domain works, I recommend using CNAME and pointing your sub-domain to your parent. Some DNS servers do not like using A records for sub-domains and some do not like using CNAME records. They are few and far in between, but they exist.

Comment: I get a timeout when I ping the subdomain. The DNS lookup points to my server IP.

Comment: I get that. Does your parent domain name work? Try using a CNAME record instead of an A record. This may solve your problem. But make sure your parent domain works first.

Comment: The parent name works. I will try using a cname instead. Thanks.

Comment: Let us know if that works. I used to be a web host and a network engineer for about 30 years. I know that sometimes A records do not work for sub-domains in some DNS servers or even the other way around. Traditionally, A CNAME is the thing to use which is one reason why I recommended it. Generally I suggest using a CNAME first unless that does not work for some reason. Then drop back and punt to an A record.

Comment: Is this a public domain, and, if so, are you willing to share the domain name and subdomain with us? Have you tried "dig +trace" for example or tools like http://dns.squish.net/ to get a lookup from a remote source?; @closetnoc I think you need a comma between "web host" and "and a network engineer" <G>

Comment: Any news or updates on this question @gdaniel? Did you manage to resolve the issue? Thank you.

Comment: As it turns out some settings were wrong in the DNS Zone file which was preventing the subdomain from working. I do not have an exact answer to what the problem was because some IT company had to make the changes themselves. But the issue had to do with wrong way of writing the CNAME parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The exact rules for when a wild card is match are specified in RFC 1034, but the rules are neither intuitive nor clearly specified. This has resulted in incompatible implementations and unexpected results when they are used.

Your DNS should look like this

1. A NAME (blank or @ on some systems) FQDN `domain.com` IP
2. A NAME www FQDN `www.domain.com` IP
3. A NAME subdomain FQDN `subdomain.domain.com` IP

Try and avoid a wild-card in the DNS.